# unstable wifi after software update

Tags: wireless

Like most of us have faced, my wifi went unstable after I installed some updates. I am sure it's the updates which has messed up things for my wifi. I also see a red triangle at the top right.

I remember tweaking things to get my wifi started when I installed ubuntu & I have also tweaked things around after faced this problem. of course after looking into many comments. Below is the result from a wireless script. Please help :).

[Wireless Script Results](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=FFwQwazS)

Comment: The link to the script output is not working.

Comment: Hi..thanks for replying back..I have updated the link & it works fine now...please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your driver needs upgraded let's do:

```
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel source
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

If wget is not installed you will need to install it.
If you still have issues after the new driver is installed post fresh information from the script so we can take a close look at your router settings.

Change your encryption in your router to wpa2 AES CCMP only not mixed mode and not TKIP.

You may want to try different channels in your router and see one works better then the other.

Set IPV6 to ignore in network manager.

Comment: Hi..I have tried the commands you have suggested..but the problem is stil persisting...wifi connects for a minute & disconnects. Here is the result from the script - http://paste.ubuntu.com/10630736/

Comment: I added more directions.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I am using a shared router & not sure if my house-mates will be able to make the above changes. Do you think re-installing the drivers would fix things? If so, can you please guide on  would I do a clean install? Thanks...

Comment: No it will not help, the only thing that might help is changing the router settings. You could be an usb adapter but getting the right one is a shot in the dark.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your suggestions. However, I have re-installed Ubuntu as I had nothing to lose & the wifi is working fine now. of course, i will hesitate to install any updates moving forward.